# how to create a program to input name and exit another words using the words of the einput

Tags: c++, ascii

example 
if the user input lilian ... take the first word's ( L) Number in ascii and add this number the number of the number of words of the name and so on with all the words in the name 
example
h=104
input 
hello
output 104+5  ....    (number of e) +5 and so on

the goal is to output new name or words from the input words

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char word[20] ;
int x=0;
cin>>word;
while(word[x] != 0)
{
    cout << int(word[x]) ;
    x++;

}

cout << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first sentence is more confusing than my tax return, and I run a large offshore business.

Comment: U wanna more information or more clearence explanation or what do u want ?

Comment: U cofuse me cuz U mix defn of word wit letr. "Lilan" is a word. 'L' is a letter.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm afraid that wasn't 1337 enough to be understood by the OP actually :P ...

Comment: Suggestion to the OP: Next time you post a question, have somebody (a friend, a colleague, who doesn't know what you are trying to do) read over your text first. If she understands your post, you will be likely to get a response. If your problem had only been a little less trivial, it would have been almost impossible to make sense of the question. For this time, see my answer below.

Comment: Iam new at c++ and programing so i cant explain it well xD in the next time i will be better ;) thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I deciphered your question. Let me know if this helps (explanation below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char word[20] ;
int x=0;

cin>>word;

size_t shift=strlen(word); //////

while(word[x] != 0)
{
    cout << char(word[x]+shift) ; //////
    x++;

}

cout << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
hello
```

Output:

```
mjqqt
```

Explanation:
The only lines I changed are the ones marked by `//////`. The first one uses the `strlen` function from `cstring` (see included header) to get the string's length. Now, for the second one: In your original code, you didn't actually add anything to `word[x]` and you had a futile cast to `int` in the `cout` statement. All you would get was numbers corresponding to the ASCII codes of the characters. In the code above, the result of `word[x]+shift` is casted back to `char`, so an actual character is printed.

Caveats:
Note that I only made the minimal changes necessary to make your program work. You have no boundary/overflow checks in your code. Unexpected things will happen if `char` overflows and you won't get alphanumeric output if an input character is near the end of the alphabet (or even not so near, if the word is long). You will have to think what you want the code to do in those cases. Also consider using `std::string` instead of `char[]` (then use the `length()` member function instead of `strlen`) and maybe writing a separate function to do the shifting and handle the special cases (wrapping around, etc.).

Comment: Thats right but i wanna make it count the number if words of char word[20]; and replace it with the number five which will add to the cout in while loop

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this matches your requirements:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  static const char letters[] =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  std::string name;
  std::cout << "Enter name: ";
  std::cin >> name;
  std::string::size_type posn = 0;
  for (posn = 0; posn < name.length(); ++posn)
  {
    char c = name[posn];
    char offset_letter;
    if (c == std::toupper(c))
    {
      offset_letter = 'A';
    }
    else
    {
      offset_letter = 'a';
    }
    if (std::isalpha(c))
    {
      c = ((c - offset_letter) + 5) % 26; // 26 letters in alphabet.
      c += offset_letter;          
    }
    std::cout << c;
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The above program inputs a name, rotates each letter by 5 and wraps around for values past end of alphabet.